# python unicode read/write not respecting new line characters

Tags: python, unicode

After a get request full of unicode text. I can print that and see that everything is formatted correctly and such shown below.

[image]

After this I write that text, to txt file stored in json format via:

```
def parse_contents(res_dict, file):

content_payload = res_dict['parse']['wikitext']['*']
sections_payload = res_dict['parse']['sections']
db = {}

def now_next_iter(iterable):
    import itertools
    a, b = itertools.tee(sections_payload)
    next(b, None)
    return itertools.izip(a, b)

def remove_tags(text):
    import re
    return re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', text)

for cur, nxt in now_next_iter(sections_payload):

    if cur['toclevel'] == 2:
        head = cur['line']
        db[head] = {}
    elif cur['toclevel']  == 3:
        line = cur['line']
        ibo = cur['byteoffset']
        fbo = nxt['byteoffset']

        content = remove_tags(content_payload[ibo:fbo])
        print content #===============> THIS IS PRINTING OUT THE STUFF IN THE PICTURE ABOVE
        db[head][line] = content

with io.open(file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as json_db:
    json_db.write(json.dumps( db, sort_keys=True, indent=4,
                ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

it gets stored like this in a txt file:
[image]
it loses the formatting, I assume thats because of the enocoding or some json dumps magic(I don't really want to know at this point). I thought it would be fine because if I do print 'sdfd \n' it prints the new line and not '\n' but thats not the case for me. It prints '\n' and has no respect for any new lines.

this is the code i used to read that file:

```
f= open("note.txt", 'r')
a = f.read()
type(a)
>>>'str'
b = a.decode('utf-8')
type(b)
>>>'unicode'
print b
```

[image]

the formating is completely gone, and the type is unicode. I tried this with io open, codecs, I don't get unicode... what am I doing wrong. I just want my new lines :( I even set sys.stdout to codecs.getwriter('utf-8')

EDIT 1: using json.loads and reading the file...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not decoding the JSON on reading?

Comment: If you want text format, use text format, not JSON. JSON has formatting rules that prevent what you're attempting.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams updated the question with an edit, sorry about cutting the text off, I don't want you to see somethings.

Comment: @MarkRansom I need to store my information in a JSON file

Comment: Copy-and-paste works wonders for that. Anyways, try printing the individual keys and values instead. You are seeing nothing strange.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I've tried that before, same result. what I dont get is that its in unicode and it see's a \n how hard is it for the damn thing to put in a new line instead

Comment: You still don't understand - JSON is a *format* for storing data. The data inside the format needs to be rigidly controlled so that the data can be extracted *exactly* as it went in. You should care about the data you insert and the data you extract, *not* the data that's stored, because you have no control over that.

Comment: @MarkRansom don't care about how its stores, the fact is I still get \n instead of actual new lines when I print, I need to fix that

Comment: Then perhaps I misunderstood and the linked question will be helpful.